# EMR Master SSH disallowed

Tags: apache-spark, ssh, amazon-emr

To run Scala spark jobs and to run spark shell queries...I have been SSHing into the Masternode of EMR and now the team that is charged to manage the cloud is not allowing me to SSH into EMR masternode. What are the alternative patterns that could be leveraged?

Comment: I was using the default "hadoop" user id and SSHing into the EMR to run spark shell queries and run Scala spark programs....is there a pattern available that wouldn't necessitate me to login to EMR Master

Comment: Question is Zepplin WebUI a good choice for running spark SQL queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zeppelin is your best best if the cloud team are happy allowing access to it.

The `%spark` interpreter is pretty much `spark-shell` running in a notebook’s paragraph.

It also imports important stuff like `spark.sql`, `SparkContext` etc. by default, so you don’t need to import anything and can just run code e.g:

```
%spark
val myDf = spark.sql(“select * from table”)
myDf.limit(10).show()

val myOtherDf = spark.read.csv(“s3://bucket/key/object.csv”)
myOtherDf.limit(10).show()
```

(`spark-shell` may do this too, but I don’t use it enough to know off hand)

As Zeppelin is actually running on the Spark Master node, you can even get access to the master node’s os using the shell interpreter `%sh` e.g.:

```
%sh
ls /
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/myfile /
```

Although your access depends on the os permissions of course.

Be aware that once you kill the cluster, your notebook will disappear too! Make sure to download it when possible.